# Change input placeholder opacity on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can change the input placeholder opacity of a text box when I click a button?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sv553ka0/)**

**HTML:**

```
<input id="textbox_id"  placeholder="some random text" type="text" />
<button type="button" onClick="btn()" >Click Me!</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#textbox_id::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    opacity:0;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
function btn(){
    //alert("test");
    $('#textbox_id::-webkit-input-placeholder').css("opacity", "1");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class with the rule `opacity: 0;` and add this class to the input when button is clicked.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/sv553ka0/3/)

```js
function btn() {
  $('#textbox_id').toggleClass("myClass");
}
```

```css
.myClass::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox_id" placeholder="some random text" type="text" />
<button type="button" onClick="btn()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, works. I slightly modified it (added fade and made it start at 0) http://jsfiddle.net/L5o19v8z/

Comment: @PatrikFröhler Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by switching out a class on the textbox: [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv553ka0/1/)

```js
function btn() {
  $('#textbox_id').removeClass('hiddenPlaceholder');
  $('#textbox_id').addClass('Placeholder');
}
```

```css
.hiddenPlaceholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.Placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox_id" class="hiddenPlaceholder" placeholder="some random text" type="text" />
<button type="button" onClick="btn()">Click Me!</button>
```